# Golden image updates in qemu

Tags: cloud, virtualization, qemu, disk, libvirt

Consider that there are 100 windows virtual machines coming from a single base image and each vm is added to domain along with minor other machine specific settings which can be done by a script.

After a week say I want to update all vms with a security patch. There are two methods to do this:

1. Destroy all vms, update base image, create all vms again.

   **Issue:** This requires all the vms to be destroyed, create disk again, define vm, then run required scripts which take care of vm specific configuration with multiple reboot cycles as required.
2. Manually update all vms and apply the security patch.

   **Issue:** Just cannot scale. May be okay for a set of 5-10 vms not 100s.

I am curious how do other people/softwares do it? Is there a better approach or can I improve my 1st method?

Comment: This should be asked on ServerFault, not StackOverflow.  Also, at that size: AmazonE2 or some other PaaS service will likely be worth the money.

Comment: Yeah I realized it and moved it to serverfault. For the AmazonE2 suggestion, I want to create something like this on my own so not looking forward to using an existing PaaS service.

Comment: Just an idea: check out OpenStack - I haven't used it, but I think it's designed exactly for this type of scenario.  Best of luck :)

Comment: Thanks @tonysdg! I am looking at the same in parallel but it will take some time to lean openstack terminology and digging their codebase :)